# Bind strings to hotkey

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to quick paste some different strings using hotkeys. For example if I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in any input form it works like if I pasted `loremipsum`. Or it  may be some abbreviation, for example I enter `li`, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and get `loremipsum`. Is it any software to do it?

I'm using Linux Mint with KDE desktop.

*In Windows I could do it using AutoHotkey*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use autokey-gtk

```
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
```

OR (my preferred solution) you can do that using xclip and xdotool:

```
sudo apt-get install xclip xdotool
```

Write a small bash script (e.g. paste_text.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
clip_content=$(xclip -selection "clipboard" -o)
echo "$1" | xclip -selection "clipboard"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key ctrl+v
echo "$clip_content" | xclip -selection "clipboard"
```

(You might need to increase the sleep-time. Maybe someone finds a better solution than sleep and comment)

then make it executable

```
chmod +x paste_text.sh
```

Then you can add as many keyboard shortcuts to the script as you wish

```
/path/to/paste_text.sh "your text"
```

(Inspired by the answers from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280604/assign-hotkeys-to-paste-predefined-text))

Comment: Thank you for answer and for link to answer about `autokey-gtk`, it looks very useful. I did not succeed to find it.

Comment: It looks like running this script will erase the current contents of your clipboard.

Comment: that is true, it's using the standard clipboard. Maybe I should mention that. Ot better change the script so that it takes care <-- Done